# jQuery Mobile change pages without animating header and footer

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile set up using multiple page files that animate, slide, when a link is pressed or an event is triggered. That works great, but when the page slides in and out, the header and footer slide too, even though they stay the same.

I know I can override the page changes and just swap out `.ui-content` but that causes other issues and requires me to redo a lot of my code.

Is there a way to keep the page changing, and page change animations but have the header and footer elements instantly change without the animation?

My code is fairly simple,

As requested, here is some of my code:

```
<!--login page-->
<div data-role="page" id="login" data-dom-cache="true" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header"  data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
            <h1>Mastrack</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content">
            <form id="loginForm">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" data-mini="true">Remember me?</label></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" id="forgotPWD">Forgot Password?</a></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="loginMessage" data-transition="pop"><p></p></div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="forgotMessage" data-transition="pop" style="padding:0px 8px;">
        <form id="forgotForm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username or E-mail">
            <input type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Get New Password">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is the login page to my site. The next page it loads is

```
<div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" id="welcome" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
            <h1>Mastrack</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content">
            Welcome <span id="custName"></span>,<br>
            <p id="messages">

            </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-id="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="notext">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#settings" class="navigation" data-icon="gear" data-transition="slide">Settings</a>
                    <a href="#devices" class="navigation" data-icon="location" data-transition="slide">Devices</a>
                    <a href="#alerts" class="navigation" data-icon="alert" data-transition="slide">Alerts</a>
                    <a href="#reports" class="navigation" data-icon="info" data-transition="slide">Reports</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Gajotres answer is partly correct, I ended up using a different solution.

In jQueryMobile 1.4.2 it seems that the data-id method for fixed navigation is not the preferable way of doing this. Instead I followed [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/toolbar-fixed-persistent/) guide from the jQueryMobile demos to create the effect. I placed my header and footer outside of the main page element and excluded headers and footers from other pages and dynamically changed the content as needed with jQuery.

Comment: Could you recreate an fiddle or something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, give header and footer data-id attribute, and make it the same, something like:

data-id="fixed"

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/JB22E/6/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="article1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
        <h1>Articles 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Article 1</p>
        <a data-role="button" id="add-dynamic-page">Add new dynamic page</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>    
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my old example, made for somthing complete else but you can use it to see how it works. As you can see header and footer have **data-id** attribute. Delete them and see what will happen.

Comment: It might be something to do with my implementation but doing that does not stop them from animating.

Comment: It looks like my footer is staying put, but my header certaintly isn't.

Comment: If possible you should add your HTML to your question. I gave you a working solution and I can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Found your problem, you were not careful, data-id should go only to header and footer div, and in your login page you put it into data-role="page" div. Plus header and footer must have same data-id value.

Comment: That was a typo on my part, my code did have the data-id on the header not the page. Also, I tried them with the same data-id value and no luck, that's why I tried changing it. As it is right now, both the header and footer on all pages have `data-id="footer"` and the header still slides.

Comment: Man I used your pages and made them slide correctly. But it doesn't matter, I gave you correct answer. This is completely different problem.

Comment: If it's the answer then how come it is not working? There is obviously something wrong, either a compatibility thing, or something I'm not doing right. I have set the `data-id` to `fixed` on every page, and the header still slides (though it gets a weird animation) but the footer stays locked. As such, I can't mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I've isolated the problem. The header content doesn't animate, but the background for the header itself does. I assume the reason the footer is "fixed" is because it is full of buttons, content.

Comment: For Gajotres or anyone else who finds this: The problem seems to be that the current version of JQM only supports fixed footers as per: [link](http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/). I tested Gajotres' JSFiddle with JQM 1.4.2 and it did not work properly. Why JQM would drop this functionality for the header I have no idea.